# SQL Server : Update Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Sequence_ID Dex_ID
1       1
null    2
null    3
2       4
null    5
null    6
3       7
null    8
null    9
4       10
null    11
null    12
3       13
```

Above is the data set. The null should be updated by the preceding values between the two not nulls. The sequence_id will not necessarily be in a specific order but the Dex_ID follows an  ascending order. 
The output should look like :

```
Sequence_ID Dex_ID
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   4
2   5
2   6
3   7
3   8
3   9
4   10
4   11
4   12
3   13
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you use? 2005? 2008?

Comment: Don't use images for text content: it is harder to read and very hard to copy and paste (eg. to test a possible solution).

Comment: @PhamX.Bach or.. a version which isnt in a museaum :D

Comment: sorry my bad ...its 2012

Comment: 2012 and later is good to use window function for your case

Comment: @PhamX.Bach : can't use a Window function becuase of "The sequence_id will not necessarily be in a specific order"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another solution to accomplish that:

[Link to Demo -> rextester](http://rextester.com/XWEG25562)

```
    DECLARE @i INT 
    ;WITH T (Sequence_ID ,Dex_ID)
    AS 
    (
    SELECT 1     ,  1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT null  ,  2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT null  ,  3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2     ,  4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT null  ,  5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT null  ,  6
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3     ,  7
    UNION ALL
    SELECT null  ,  8
    UNION ALL
    SELECT null  ,  9
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4     ,  10
    UNION ALL
    SELECT null  ,  11
    UNION ALL
    SELECT null  ,  12
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3     ,  13
    )
    SELECT * 
    INTO #T
    FROM T
    /*The fill up of the null*/
    UPDATE #T 
    SET @i = Sequence_ID = CASE WHEN  Sequence_ID is null THEN @i Else Sequence_ID END

    SELECT *
    FROM #T

    DROP TABLE #T
```

Comment: Elegant, but not obvious to most people

Comment: And I broke it sorry http://rextester.com/ENMZ33069 with `CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UXC_t ON #T (Dex_ID DESC)`

Comment: @gbn, you are right, the order is critical for this approach to work.

Comment: You can force the order as per my second example. It's a great solution though

Answer (score 6):

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5c3c2/1)

```
UPDATE
    f1
SET
    Sequence_ID = x.Sequence_ID
FROM
    MyTable f1
    CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT TOP (1) Sequence_ID
     FROM MyTable f2 
     WHERE f2.Dex_ID < f1.Dex_ID 
       AND f2.Sequence_ID IS NOT NULL 
       AND f1.Sequence_ID IS NULL
     ORDER BY f2.Dex_ID desc
     ) x
WHERE
    f1.Sequence_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: If there are two more rows (null,14) and (null,15), then the sequence_id for Dex_id 14 and 15 should be 3 depending on the value at Dex_ID 13. The above query works until dex_id 13 but gives incorrect value for next two rows.

Comment: @Dimple fixed, new SQLFiddle link too

Answer (score 0):

The following solution uses Itzik Ben-Gan's first solution in his article [The Last non NULL Puzzle](http://www.itprotoday.com/software-development/last-non-null-puzzle).

Run it at: [**db<>fiddle**](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=dcba3c4921fd0254e115084737b6bce4)

#### Data

```
CREATE TABLE #T 
(
    Sequence_ID integer NULL, 
    Dex_ID integer PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT #T
    (Sequence_ID, Dex_ID)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (NULL, 2),
    (NULL, 3),
    (2, 4),
    (NULL, 5),
    (NULL, 6),
    (3, 7),
    (NULL, 8),
    (NULL, 9),
    (4, 10),
    (NULL, 11),
    (NULL, 12),
    (3, 13),
    (NULL, 14),
    (NULL, 15);
```

#### Solution

```
WITH 
    Grouped AS
    (
        SELECT
            T.Sequence_ID,
            T.Dex_ID,
            TargetDex_ID =
                MAX(IIF(T.Sequence_ID IS NULL, NULL, T.Dex_ID)) OVER (
                    ORDER BY T.Dex_ID ASC
                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
        FROM #T AS T
    ),
    Sequenced AS
    (
        SELECT
            G.Sequence_ID,
            G.Dex_ID,
            NewSequence_ID =
                MAX(G.Sequence_ID) OVER (
                    PARTITION BY G.TargetDex_ID
                    ORDER BY G.Dex_ID
                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
        FROM Grouped AS G
    )
UPDATE Sequenced
SET Sequenced.Sequence_ID = Sequenced.NewSequence_ID;

SELECT
    T.Sequence_ID,
    T.Dex_ID 
FROM #T AS T
ORDER BY
    T.Dex_ID;
```

#### Output

> ```
>  
> Sequence_ID | Dex_ID
> ----------: | -----:
>           1 |      1
>           1 |      2
>           1 |      3
>           2 |      4
>           2 |      5
>           2 |      6
>           3 |      7
>           3 |      8
>           3 |      9
>           4 |     10
>           4 |     11
>           4 |     12
>           3 |     13
>           3 |     14
>           3 |     15
> ```

#### Other solutions

- Itzik's second method based on concatenation
- `TOP` as in gbn's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49231069)
- Use a SQLCLR function to read the data in order and compute the desired value per row.
- [Vote for Microsoft to implement `LAG` with `IGNORE NULLS`](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32897728-add-language-support-for-null-treatment-clause-re)

**Avoid the variable assignment solution.**

SQL Server only guarantees variable assignment behaviour when a single row is updated.

> From the documentation [`UPDATE (Transact-SQL)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql#best-practices):
>
> Variable names can be used in UPDATE statements to show the old and new values affected, but this should be used only when the UPDATE statement affects a single record. If the UPDATE statement affects multiple records, to return the old and new values for each record, use the [OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql).

This is the only intended and supported usage. People have experimented with ways to make this ["quirky update"](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/) reliable over the years, but it is an absolute minefield and simply best avoided completely.